# Problema ao tentar dividir um array de numeros ordenados aleatoriamente em duas partes iguais usando Godot/GDScript

Tags: array, números-aleatórios, order, gdscript

Estou atualmente criando um jogo em Godot 3.2.3, e neste jogo eu preciso criar um array que contenha numeros de 1 até `array.size()` (exemplo:[0,1,2,...,30]) e que tais numeros estejam em ordem aleatória, para posteriormente serem divididos em 2 sub arrays.

O código abaixo demonstra o processo:

```
func createImageSets(var size):
var arr = Array()
var n = 1
while (n <= size):
    arr.append(n)
    n = n + 1
arr.shuffle()
var half = size/2
study_set = arr.slice(0,half-1)
other_set = arr.slice(half, size-1)
print(study_set)
print(other_set)
```

obs: `study_set` e `other_set` são variaveis do script.

Quando tento printar os sub arrays, tenho este resultado:

```
[11, 16, 5, 25, 12, 2, 27, 17, 23, 21, 14, 7, 19, 13, 9]
[6, 10, 26, 24, 29, 3, 1, 8, 15, 18, 4, 22, 28, 20, 30]
```

Percebi que todas as vezes que executo este script, a ordem dos numeros gerado no `shuffle()` é a mesma, como se o método não criasse uma nova instancia pra gerar o embaralhamento entre uma execução e outra. Não importa quantas vezes execute, o resultado sempre é estes mesmos 2 arrays.

Eu gostaria que cada execução me fornecesse conjuntos diferentes de numeros.
Alguém poderia me ajudar nisso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem que chamar `randomize()` antes do `arr.shuffle()`.

```
extends Node2D

var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

func _ready():
    randomize()
    a.shuffle()
    for i in range(9):
        print(a[i])
```

Link pra você testar: [Aqui.](https://gd.tumeo.space/KYDwLsB2AmDOAEA5A9tYAmAIgKGwNwEMAneA+AXngG0BGAGnToGY6AWOgVjoDY6B2OgA46ATgC6uAGYBXSAGN4AfSLAC0AJ4AKAJQAubPEPwiBGMgC2ASwBewHQaMEAdLAAW0yZIA2d7Q8OSyCSW8JaQxqYA5nYiev5GhgAORGFgmgRUlmLaQA)

Fonte: [QA - godotengine.org](https://godotengine.org/qa/48029/how-to-shuffle-array-by-randomize-function?show=48036#a48036)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Está funcionando devidamente agora, e agradeço também pelo link de teste, muito interessante esta plataforma